# Remove last curly brace in javascript with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi i need some help to remove last curly braces, } from a dynamic string.

I recieve a dynamic string that can be longer or smaller sometimes, but i need to remove the last } in the string

I was thinking of using regex, but how can i acchieve this with a dynamic string that changes?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can do this to remove the last `}` of a string :

```
s = s.replace(/\}([^}]*)$/,'$1')
```

Comment: Could also use [lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) and some string manipulation (possibly easier to understand for those unfamiliar with regexes). +1. (I completely agree that all devs should have "can use regexes" in their toolbelt - but many do not leading to "I had a problem, I decided to use a regex, now I've got 2 problems"-ness =))

Comment: Yes, that's possible, but that's more verbose (mainly because you need to store the index because you use it twice in the string slicing) and regexes are so damn useful that all programmers should learn them anyway.

Answer (score 3):

dystroy's answer is correct, but in the interest of completeness: you could use a negative look-ahead assertion, too:

```
var s = 'f}oo}bar';
s = s.replace(/}(?!.*})/, '');
console.log(s);//f}oobar
```

Basically this regex replaces a single closing curly brace, if it's the last (or only) `}` char in the string.
how it works:

- `}`: matches a literal } char
- `(?!` negative look-ahead: matches the `}` only if it is *not* followed by:
- `.*}`: zero or more chars, followed by a closing curly

Comment: +1. [Using a negative look ahead here is much faster](http://jsperf.com/remove-last-curly-brace-in-javascript-with-regex).

Comment: After second though, even if I don't doubt your solution is faster, I think part of the difference (string operation) is probably a jsperf artifact (jsperf preventing compilation).

Comment: @dystroy: JS has always been, and probably always be a tricky bugger to accurately benchmark, but I think a negative look-ahead assertion here is faster, owing to the fact it doesn't group, and only replaces a single char, not replace a match with a group. But as ever, I could be wrong here, too

Comment: I verified with friends of the JS room : your regex may be slower (as tested with `test`). What is faster is the string operation, probably because the '$1' temporary string isn't optimized (not sure if it would be much better outside of jsperf though). For short strings the results are very different but such a replacement makes probably more sense in bigger strings.